# How do I convert a string to different substrings and place it into a variable?

Tags: mysql

I have a string variable that that is: **“black, white, yellow”**. The problem is i’m using a Where IN clause in sql and i need to put the string variable into the sql statement. For eg. Select * FROM Products WHERE Products.color IN (?)

If i pass the string variable into the sql statement it will become Select * FROM Products WHERE Products.color  IN (**“black,white,yellow”**)

However, the correct syntax should be Select * FROM Products WHERE Products.color  IN (**“black” , “white” , “yellow”**)

How should i overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try using `FIND_IN_SET`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Products
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(color, 'black,white,yellow') > 0;
```

### Demo

Note carefully that the CSV string of colors has *no* spaces in it.  If your actual string has spaces, then you may first remove them inside Go, or directly from the MySQL query.

And also, in general, it is not desirable to store CSV data in SQL tables.  `FIND_IN_SET` gets you around the problem for the time being, but long term you should consider storing each color in a separate record.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the function below which will read the comma separated string variable (“black, white, yellow”) into an XML file and load into a temp table.

```
drop table #Product_Converted
CREATE TABLE #Product_Converted
(
Product NVARCHAR(20) NULL
)


declare @product varchar(max) ='black, white, yellow'
DECLARE @product1 AS XML


DECLARE @Delimiter AS CHAR(1) =','

SET @Product1 = CAST(('<X>'+REPLACE(@Product ,@Delimiter ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') AS XML)

--Get all comma separated state values to rows of a table

INSERT INTO #Product_Converted
SELECT N.value('.', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS ID FROM @Product1.nodes('X') AS T(N)

select * from #Product_Converted
```

Final result will be:

```
Select * FROM Products WHERE Products.color IN (select product from #Product_Converted)
```